# Converting an object to another class at runtime but able to use the member before runtime

Tags: c#, object

User can choose between three connections to use.

1. Sqlite
2. SQL Server
3. MySQL

I currently have three methods that do the same things. I wish to do something like this

```
object obj;

if (connectionchosen == "Sqlite")
  obj = new SqlLiteConnection("connectiongstring);

if (connectionchosen == "MSSQL")
 ojb = new SqlConnection("connectionstring);

if (connectionchosen == "MySQL")
 obj = new MySqlConnection("connectionstring);
```

Apparently, the above can't be done since obj can't see the Sqlite / SQL Server / Mysql members unless it's properly casted/converted.

How can I convert the above obj to one of the three using the IF's above and be able to use the members?

Example:

```
public static bool LOGIN(string USERNAME, string PASSWORD,GLOBALFUNCTIONS.DBS DB)
{
   try
   {
      bool val = false;
      OPENDB(DB);
      object cmd;

      if (DB == GLOBALFUNCTIONS.DBS.SQLLOCAL)
      {
         _CN.SQLLITECMD = new SQLiteCommand("select * from users where        username='" + USERNAME + "' and password='" + _GLOBAL.GLOBALFUNCTIONS.GETMD5(PASSWORD + USERNAME) + "'",_CN.SQLLITELOCAL);
         _CN.SQLLITEREADER = _CN.SQLLITECMD.ExecuteReader();

         if (_CN.SQLLITEREADER.Read())
         {
            val = true;
                            _GLOBAL.GLOBALFUNCTIONS.LOGIN(_CN.SQLLITEREADER[0].ToString(), val, _CN.SQLLITEREADER[2].ToString(), GLOBALVARS.DATABASE);
         }
         else
                            _GLOBAL.GLOBALFUNCTIONS.LOGIN(_CN.SQLLITEREADER[0].ToString(), val, _CN.SQLLITEREADER[2].ToString(), GLOBALVARS.DATABASE);
                        _GLOBAL.GLOBALFUNCTIONS.AUDIT(USERNAME, _CN.SQLLITECMD.CommandText, GLOBALVARS.DATABASE);
    }
    CLOSEDB(DB);
    return val;
}
catch (Exception)
{
   CLOSEDB(DB);
   return false;
}
```

replace all

```
_CN.SQLITECMD/_CN.SQLLITEREADER/_CN.SQLLITELOCAL
```

with

```
_CN.MSSQLCMD/_CN.MSSQLREADER/_CN.MSSQLLOCAL
```

Instead I wish to simple use CMD/READER/LOCAL for all three different connections.

I hope I'm clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: You should definitely learn to use **parametrized queries** to avoid SQL injection attacks! **DO NOT** just concatenate together your SQL statements! This is **NOT SAFE**

Comment: Sounds like an interface with the Methods that you are after could do wonders. Have you looking into finding a common Interface for the 3 Types?

Comment: What @Bazzz said. `IDbConnection` is the standard System.Data interface that all connections share.

Comment: marc_s: Yes, i will later on use parameterized queries , "select * from users where username=@p1 and password=@p2" then do cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1",varchar(50),value);

Tim Medora: IDbConnection, IDbCommand,IDataReader, IDbDataAdapter looks like fixed things. I haven't compiled yet to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By basing your code around the [`IDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.aspx) inteface you can abstract to concrete connection type.

```
IDbConnection connection;

if (connectionchosen == "Sqlite")
  connection= new SqlLiteConnection("connectiongstring);

if (connectionchosen == "MSSQL")
  connection = new SqlConnection("connectionstring);

if (connectionchosen == "MySQL")
  connection = new MySqlConnection("connectionstring);
```

To create a command you then have to use the [`IDbConnection.CreateCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbconnection.createcommand.aspx) method which will create the correct type of command depending on the type of the connection. You will then be limited to working with `IDbCommand` instead of the more specific `SqlCommand`, `SQLiteCommand` etc. meaning that you will not have access to provider specific features. But that is the price to pay if you want be agnostic about the underlying provider.

Instead of making your own factory logic (as shown above) you can build on top of the ADO.NET [DbProviderFactories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wda6c36e.aspx). This will allow you to configure your data source in `App.config` and avoid any provider specific code in your implementation.

Comment: Not sure what you make of your comment but the whole point of my answer it that you should avoid hardcoding types like `SQLiteCommand` etc. in you code. Instead you should use a factory to create connections, commands etc. Your code will only depend on the ADO.NET interfaces and at a single point in your code do you decide which factory to use (e.g. the SQLite factory, the SQL Server factory etc.).

Comment: I have no idea of DbProviderFactories. I will have a read . Thank you. The above code worked though not having to hardcode types is better. I hope this also works in windows application as well. 
Thank you.